# How can I send arbitrary data as part of an Ogg or Matroska stream in a GStreamer application?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have live audio and video data that I can either send as an Ogg or Matroska (WebM) stream. I also have dynamic metadata that will be sent from the server to the client, and should be correlated with the A/V streams. For example, the exact server time when the audio packet was recorded.

I attempted to hack this with Kate encoding, but that appears to send all the subtitle data at once in the beginning, and not dynamically as it happens. If you could tell me how to send well-correlated dynamic subtitle data, then that's a viable solution as well.

Comment: Have you tried to overlay the subtitle data with your video at the source/server and then send it to client?

Comment: My apologies, to be more clear, I'm not trying to actually send subtitle data for the use of subtitles: I'm trying to encode arbitrary data to be received by the client, in any way possible. So, it cannot be overlayed on the video, because it's not intended for viewing directly.

Comment: I think [Appsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html) suffices your case.